# Weird Google Maps V2 Marker issue

Tags: google-maps

Got this code, that only works when alert (markers.length); is uncommented.

When this javascript alert not shown I dont get any Markers.. Really weird!!

In the body tag I have `<body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">`

Previoslly the load() function is called and other functions :

```
         function showAddress(address) {
           if (geocoder) {//+', '+init_street
    geocoder.getLatLng(address,
        function(point) {
                if (!point) {
                  document.getElementById("place").value="not found";
                  //alert(address + " not found");
                } else {
                //  document.getElementById("place").value=point.y.toFixed(4) + "," + point.x.toFixed(4);
                    map.setCenter(point, 16);
                    marker.setPoint(point);
                    //marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address);
                }
            }
    );
}
           }

         //from a point returns and address!
      function showPointAddress(response) {
  if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {//not found
    //alert("Status Code:" + response.Status.code);
      document.getElementById("place").value="not found";
  } 
  else {//found
        map.setCenter(marker.getPoint(), 16);
        place = response.Placemark[0];
        document.getElementById("place").value=place.address;
        //document.getElementById("place").value=marker.getPoint().toUrlValue();
  }
         }


            // Creates a marker at the given point with the given number icon and text
          function createMarker(p,text) {
var marker = new GMarker(p);
if (text!=""){
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(text);});
      }
return marker;
      }


          ` var geocoder = null;`
          ` var map = null;`


      function load() {//loading the map
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

        if (init_street!=""){
            geocoder.getLatLng(init_street,function(point) {//set center point in map
                if (point){
                    map.setCenter(point, zoom);
                    map.addOverlay(createMarker(point,init_street));
                    map.openInfoWindow(point,init_street);
                }
            });
        }

        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
        map.setMapType(G_NORMAL_MAP);           
  }
}`




function(data, responseCode) {
  if(responseCode == 200) {
        var texts = [];
        var addresses = [];       
        var xml = GXml.parse(data);
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("item");
        alert (markers.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
            var address=markers[i].getElementsByTagName('address').item(0).childNodes.item(0).nodeValue;
            if (address!=null){
                //alert (address);
                var title=markers[i].getElementsByTagName('title').item(0).childNodes.item(0).nodeValue;
                var link=markers[i].getElementsByTagName('link').item(0).childNodes.item(0).nodeValue;
                var desc=markers[i].getElementsByTagName('description').item(0).childNodes.item(0).nodeValue;
                desc=desc.substr(0,220);//limit
                addresses.push(address);
                texts.push("<div style='width: 200px'><a target='_blank' href='" +link+"'>"+title+"</a><br />"+desc+"</div>");
            }//if
         }//for

        for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) { 
            geocoder.getLatLng(addresses[i], function (current) { 
                return function(point) { 
                    if (point) map.addOverlay(createMarker(point,texts[current]));    
                } 
            }(i)); 
        }

  }//if });
```

I Understand the issue of needing a callback function to load the markers, but Im lost..

Any help apreciated!! ;)

Thx in advanced!!

Comment: I guess this is following a `GDownloadUrl` call. I can't see any reason why an alert which simply delays processing the result should make a difference to `GDownloadUrl`. Do you have a link (preferable)? Or more context (not as useful)?

Comment: Sorry, no URL yet... And Yes, GdownloadUrl is as following: 

`GDownloadUrl("/rss/?category=<?php echo $_GET["category"];?>&type=<?php echo $_GET["type"];?>",`

Didnt copy in first post... 

 This returns: `GDownloadUrl("/rss/?category=casa-rural&type=1",`

 Really Odd... I just need to splash an alert and my markers appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when fetching data with Ajax or similar. Basically when you fetch the data you need to utilize a callback function to wait for the data. If you don't there is no data to execute on. However, if you pause the execution with a alert() the data will have been fetched in the background.

Think of it as the waiting for the DOM to load before executing Javascript on the page.

I can't give you a better answer as you have not included the code that is calling the function you included.

Comment: Ok.. makes sense... ;) Ill look in to this and get back if needed!! Thx!!

Comment: Ive  updated my post with more info... If I get any response I would be really thankfull...

Comment: Missed your reply, are you still interested in more info?